# How do I implement delegate methods through Swift extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiapplicationdelegate, swift-extensions

My project is a mix of Obj-C and Swift, and I'm trying to extend my AppDelegate class with Swift.

So right now I have `AppDelegate.m`, `AppDelegate.h`, and `AppDelegate.swift`. Most of the methods are in the Obj-C file, but I'm trying to implement just one of the methods:

```
extension AppDelegate {

    func application(application: UIApplication, continueUserActivity userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: ([AnyObject]?) -> Void) -> Bool {

    }
}
```

However it's complaining:

```
AppDelegate.swift:11:10: Method 'application(_:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:)' with Objective-C selector 'application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:' conflicts with previous declaration with the same Objective-C selector
```

Is this a limitation of Swift extension? Or is there a way to implement this delegate method in my Swift extension file?

Comment: if you want to override an existing method, you will have to subclass instead of writing an extension

Comment: @simpleBob It's not an existing method, I haven't implemented it in my Obj-C class.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do something like that. `AppDelegate` has defined this method (`UIApplicationDelegate` protocol says so).

The simplest solution would be to rewrite`AppDelegate` in swift.

You have also more difficult solution - remove `UIApplicationDelegate` from your `AppDelegate` and implement this protocol in your extension. It may raise unexpected errors if your `AppDelegate` is considerable size.

Comment: Ok, let's say this is a view controller instead with a `TableViewDelegate` methods that needs to be implemented. Can I extend my view controller and implement those methods there instead? If so how come it works in that scenario but not here? (P.S. My app delegate is not that big anyway so it's not a big deal to rewrite it in Swift)

Comment: It will work if you have `SomeViewController ` (subclass of `UIViewController `) and extension for this VC with protocol `UITableViewDelegate`.

But it will fail if you create `SomeViewController` (subclass of `UIViewController`) and `UITableViewController` protocol and then you create extension for `SomeViewController` with methods described in extension.